# On communication, tone deafness, and engaging constructively with folks in email communications with users

Tags: discussion, email

I had an *interesting* set of emails sent to me, ostensibly by marketing. Apparently there's a different set of emails sent to others, and there's a [negative response to that as well on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397895/did-i-just-get-told-off-by-email-if-so-what-did-i-do). Admittedly as a user with 100k + on Super User, and 80k+ on Meta (A good chunk of that is hopefully sharing the knowledge of a decade of using the Network.), I probably am in a minority but...  I had two emails on how to use search (one per account - we'll get to that).

[image: Find what you want, faster / Tips and tricks for searching on Stack Overflow]

There's a perfectly good, organic set of hints on how to search. There's help for searching. We're often told to be less condescending to new users. Maybe its just me - but the mail about feels almost like we're talking down to folks, as if they don't know how to use search - even if the dupe finder tends to work better.

Since I have two accounts here, one under a gmail alias, I got two emails each with a different footer

[image: Have you heard about Stack Overflow for Teams?]

Yanno? This is fine. I do get SE needs to try to promote its paid products. I do know about it, I guess, being a moderator and all

[image: Take a break and learn about the worst coder in the world]

Yes, we know who is the self professed worst coder in the world. I'm not sure why its in an email footer, or what the benefit is. At least with the other one, it might "sell" teams to a casual user.

If it's an A/B test... I wonder how the responses are taken.

Considering the examples given, I'd guess they're written for a programming audience - and I'm 'merely' technical, and lots of folks who use SE are not *and can use search*, could we consider tone, what's getting promoted and the audience in future marketing emails?

Comment: I got this too, was very confused as I am not active on SO and even gave away my association bonus for a bounty for someone else's question. I have never had an email from SO before. I really hope they don't intend to spam my email with this kind of stuff.

Comment: Oh, my interaction with SO is limited to the teams I use as a moderator and maintaining this one answer :D

Comment: Does anyone know how to unsubscribe from this? I clicked the unsubscribe link in the email and it took me to my SO email setting but I already unchecked every option there. I REALLY don't need tips on how to use the site or patronising "be nice" emails. I can't ask and the MSO post, no rep.

Comment: Actually - that everything is unsubscribed, and they keep sending you emails would be an issue for meta (or support), especially in this context IMO

Comment: That is fair, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348784/why-am-i-reciving-marketing-emails-from-so-when-i-have-unchecked-every-option-in

Comment: They should have added this condition (at a minimum) to the selection query: `and Users.CreationDate > DateDiff(y,-1, GETDATE())` ...

Comment: Also if they want people to find results, improving their search behaviour would be more beneficial then the hints in this email...

Comment: might want to edit in that SE has responded to this in the [SO meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/397898/4667934) as it doesn't look like they will be responding to this separately or I guess post it as a separate answer here (I would post this answer with a link but then I would need to downvote myself for such a crummy answer)