# Why am I receiving marketing emails from SO when I have unchecked every option in the email settings?

Tags: support, bug, status-review, email, email-settings-page

I received the email that is being discussed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348781/on-communication-tone-deafness-and-engaging-constructively-with-folks#348781). The thing is, I don't subscribe to any emails in the settings on SO.

It seems like a bit of an oversight that a user who went out of their way to not get this kind of marketing emails is now receiving them.

I clicked the unsubscribe link in the email and it took me to my SO email settings, where as mentioned all the options are unchecked.

How can I unsubscribe from these emails?

Comment: [Stop sending me emails I didn't sign up for](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346515/stop-sending-me-emails-i-didnt-sign-up-for)... again :)