# Stack Overflow reminded me to accept an answer. I have never posted a question

Tags: bug, email

I am a new user of Stack Overflow.  I got an email message from the site today that said "You’ve asked, now it’s time to accept an answer."  According to both my memory and my Profile page, I haven't posted a question (before this one on Meta, which is really a report, not a question).  This seems like a bug.  I tried to report this and my report was closed as resolved with a message telling me to post here.  So here I am, reporting in case anyone cares.

Edit:  I checked and confirmed that the message from Stack Overflow Support, also identified as Stack Overflow Team, did direct me to https://meta.stackexchange.com/.

Edit:  I don't have a question here, but [Why am I receiving marketing emails from SO when I have unchecked every option in the email settings?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348784/why-am-i-receiving-marketing-emails-from-so-when-i-have-unchecked-every-option-i) does not apply.  In that case, a user was receiving messages even though he thought he had turned them off and Catija found he had missed a setting.  In my case, I don't know what my email settings are, but no matter what they are, I think I should not be getting a message that refers to a nonexistent question.

Comment: The e-mail situation appears to be getting a lot weirder lately. You're not the first to mention issues of this variety.

Comment: Cross site duplicate of [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398301/received-email-people-have-given-you-solutions-but-none-of-my-questions-ha)

Comment: Hiya! These emails were sent to SO users only, so MSO is the appropriate place for this - but I can understand it being hard to know that! There's actually [a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398301/received-email-people-have-given-you-solutions-but-none-of-my-questions-ha) there already.

Comment: @Catija The OP mentioned that their report/ticket was closed and was routed here, to MSE. Perhaps that message should change based on the situation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I receiving marketing emails from SO when I have unchecked every option in the email settings?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348784/why-am-i-receiving-marketing-emails-from-so-when-i-have-unchecked-every-option-i)

Comment: @Spevacus While that would be preferable, the support team is not always aware of the specifics of each issue to know that it is a site-specific issue. We usually only route users to MSO specifically if it is clearly about Jobs.